# How to understand `Convert a vector-form distance vector to a square-form distance matrix`?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I read [scipy document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html):

```
Convert a vector-form distance vector to a square-form distance matrix, and vice-versa.
```

I don't understand this statement.

please give me a linear algebra example to explain it.

how to understand the `vector-form distance vector` and `square-form distance matrix`.

---

**EDIT-01**

how to represent `vector-form distance vector` and `square-form distance matrix` by Mathematical language?

Comment: You might want to contextualise the problem and look up: [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the putative distance matrix
$$
\mathbf{D}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 100 & 400 \\
100 & 0 & 500 \\
400 & 500 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It is a symmetric matrix
with zeros on the diagonal
and positive entries.
Another way to store this matrix
is to consider the vectorized (condensed) form
$$
\mathbf{d}=
\begin{pmatrix}
100 \\
400 \\
500
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The Python function *squareform*
allows you to go from one representation
to the other.

Comment: Whethey any matrix can be squareformed?  there you only give the speacial matrix.